# Arguments against static int pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, static

I'm about to debug someone else's code and I stumbled across a certain 'way' of handling with global arrays which I consider deeply bad, but the one who first used it swears to it. 
I need to find arguments against it.
Here is the code written simplified (this is not the original code, just an abstracted version)

So my question: which arguments would you bring against (or maybe some code which brings down this method) this?

```
int test(int i, int v, int type, int** t)
{
    static int *teeest;
    int result = 0;
    switch(type)
    {
        case (1):
            {
                int testarr[i];
                teeest = testarr;
            }
        break;
        case (2):
            result = teeest[i];
        break;
        case (3):
            teeest[i] = v;
        break;
    }
    if (t != NULL)
    {
        *t = teeest;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int *te = (int*)1;
    test(5, 0, 1, &te);
    printf("%p\n", te);
    int i=0;
    for(;i<5;i++)
    {
        test(i, i, 3, NULL);
        printf("Value: %d\n", test(i,0,2, NULL));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that's worse than a global array. as that adds function call overhead to its access.

Comment: Whoever wrote this should be fired/kicked off the team/whatever is equivalent, or at least transferred to the blackhat department, because that's really the only place hideous hacks like this that depend on implementation details have any usefulness.

Comment: I always laugh about implementations when you can ask 5 developers and every single developer gives a different reason why a piece of code is a bad idea. If you can't even all agree on why a piece of code is bad but all agree it's bad. It really is time to rework it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

local variables are dead after the block they declared in, so this code is undefined behavior. Like every accessing random address, it may work, but it also may not work.

Note that if you use `malloc` instead of `int testarr[i]`, (and worry to free the previous array, and to initialize teeest), it will be correct. the problems of this code have nothing about static pointers.

Comment: the one who wrote it said that the compiler would recognise this and handle both equal, what i consider totally mad to rely on. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user1159208 - Nope, the compiler will *not* handle that.

Answer (score 2):

This is really bad. Just because the pointer is static doesn't mean the data it points to will be around. For example, testarr disappears when the function exits and the returned pointer, if used, might cause dragons to appear.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me the big downfall of this style is that you are hiding the fact that you are accessing a locally declared array which is on the stack. Then you persist a pointer to your stack which will persist through calls, which will have different stacks each call.

Another thing I was thinking about is that you have hidden from the developer what the data structure is. Indexing an array is a normal operation. Indexing a pointer makes the developer acknowledge it is an array and not a more complex data type. This also adds confusion to bounds checking.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing is, that all disadvantages of global variables apply directly. The code is not reentrant, and hard to make thread-safe (if that's a concern).